# Optimization of a sum of absolute values of vector entries

Tags: optimization

> Minimize  $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{10} L_{i}x_{i}$  subject   to  $Af=p$ and $x \geq|f|$.

Here  $L$, $p$  and $A$ are known, $f$ and $x$ unknown.  $Af=p$ is underdetermined.

Since $x$ is minimized when $|f|$ is minimized, I rewrote the problem putting $x  = |f|$:

> Minimize $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{10} L_{i}|f_{i}|$  subject  to $ Af=p$.

Problem is, how do you solve it with the absolute value. I am using Matlab with the linprog function, but I'm unsure how to put in the parameters.

Comment: In your first form, you have a linear program since you can write $x\ge |f|$ as $x\ge f$ and $x\ge -f$. Your second form is less easy to solve.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that the weights $L_{i}$ are nonnegative, you can formulate your problem as:

$\min \sum_{i=1}^{10} L_{i}x_{i}$

subject to

$Af=p$

$x \geq f$

$x \geq -f$

The constraints ensure that $x \geq |f|$, and the nonnegative weights insure that $ x  = |f|$.  This is a standard problem transformation discussed in many textbooks on linear programming and convex optimization.